# Hyperactive DHCP and related issues

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have a simple home network - modem --> Nighthawk router --> D-Link 24 port switch --> bunch of clients (including three Ubiquiti APs - nobody uses the router wifi at all).  I put the Nighthawk router in to replace my Asus router after I started to experience DHCP issues - browsers on multiple PCs were reporting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, and phones had problems connecting to the internet via the Ubiquiti APs.  I thought the DHCP server in the router was dying.  However, I'm getting the same issues with the Nighthawk, so something else has to be causing the issues.  I also stopped the routers from using my local Pihole VM as DNS server, and that did not help.

The LAN appears to be working fine (Plex server has no issues with any clients on the LAN, for example).  I can't see that anyone's connected another router to the network (I'd kill them if they did!).

Other symptoms: my main PC (which is on a DHCP reservation to have a "static" IP) works fine all day long, but I have to reboot the router first thing in the morning otherwise I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (nothing else needs to be rebooted to regain internet access).  I'm also noticing that new IP addresses get issued to my devices repeatedly during the day - so my printer (no DHCP address reservation), for example, will get a new IP address almost every hour / multiple times per day, along with my IP phones (that do have reservations) that complain about DHCP errors.

It's possible that the Nighthawk also has a dying DHCP server, but I can't help feeling that's so unlikely.  Could my D-Link switch be dying, somehow, and causing these issues?  Is there anything else I'm missing?  Is it time to get a dedicated OPNsense box?  Please help me regain my sanity!

EDIT

Woke up this morning with my printer saying the following:

IPV4 address 169.254.XX.XX

Gateway: 192.168.1.1

Mask: 255.255.0.0 (should be 255.255.255.0)

How the heck does an address of 169.254.whatever get issued by a gateway/DHCP server on 192.168.1.1?

Rebooting the printer forced it to get a new address in the correct subnet (this time, 192.168.1.38, and mask 255.255.255.0).

Note that this issue isn't isolated to the printer - my Polycoms also suffer.

Comment: So I think there is some confusion here... DHCP only gives clients their configuration information when they boot, connect to the network, or their DHCP lease expires and they need to renew it. It is a configuration protocol and not a routing protocol. When these errors occur, I would be interested in what IP address, subnet, gateway, and DNS servers these device(s) have at that time, and what a ping to the gateway and DNS IP addresses results in, as well as to 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Using more than one DHCP could make clients confused

Comment: Doing "route -n" on my server shows only one gateway, the correct one.

Comment: root@slave:/home/adam# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.350 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.293 ms

Comment: root@slave:/home/adam# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=25.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=21.2 ms

Comment: The router log shows the same device getting multiple IP addresses throughout the day.  Example:
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.29)] to MAC address 80:C5:F2:D0:A8:XX, Wednesday, Aug 04,2021 14:10:52
[DHCP IP: (192.168.1.30)] to MAC address 80:C5:F2:D0:A8:XX, Wednesday, Aug 04,2021 02:09:03

Comment: Connectivity is there when it "fails" as pings still route through and, you can still ping out to the Internet, indicating maybe there is a name resolution issue... Are we sure this isn't a DNS issue more so than DHCP issue? Also, verify you have only ONE DHCP server in your broadcast domain. You can kill the power on your main router/DHCP server and do a release/renew of your IP address and see if you still get one. If you do, then you have a rogue DHCP server, if not, move on to something else.

Comment: But as you point out, unless a device reboots or the lease expires, why would new IP addresses get issued?  I have devices all over the house complaining about this, recently, and I didn't think leases were as short as a couple of hours, and even if so, these devices (like my Polycom IP phones) shouldn't be posting "DHCP error" and "IP address changed" messages every couple of hours.  Will repeat the tests tomorrow a.m. before I have to reboot the router again :)